# Image as a background for column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a template which will have a column on a left hand side with an image as its background. On this image I would like to insert form inputs, which amount can differ depending on need.

However, now I have an image in background which size depends on how many lines I provide.

What can I do to fill the column with given image without crossing this column's border?

For now I have something like this:

```
<style>
  .image-left{
      background-image: url('some_url.jpg');
  }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row content">
    <div class="col-md-7 sidenav text-left image-left img-fluid">
        <p>adasda sdasdasdasdasd ddddddd </p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
        <p>Test line</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 sidenav">
        <p>Test line</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can play with `background-size` property
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

if you can grow your image to fill all the element where it is place you can do

```
background-size: cover;
```

but if your image need a specific width and height you can also provide with

```
background-size: width height
background-size: 50px 100%;
```

be careful this last config will deform your image